# Chrome Extension Help (Unterminated String)?

Tags: java, jquery, html, google-chrome

So i'm currently developing a Chrome web extension, but whenever I try to upload it, it comes up with "Error: manifest.json5:0 unterminated string". Is anyone able to help me fix this? It seems to be the only file that has a problem.

```
   {
       "browser_action": {
          "default_icon": "icon.png",
          "default_popup": "popup.html”,
       "description": “Damn Daniel!”,
    },
       "manifest_version": 2,
       "name": ““,
       "permissions": [ "activeTab" ],
       "version": "0.69”,
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using curly quotes `”`. These are their own hexidecimal characters and different from the straight-quote which programming uses (`"`). This probably arose from copy and pasting from a word document.

You also put commas before your closing `}`'s. That's a no-no, as comma means it's expecting another json field to be there.

This is the valid json without the curly quotes and erroneous commas:

```
 {
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "description": "Damn Daniel!"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "",
    "permissions": ["activeTab"],
    "version": "0.69"
 }
```

I'd recommend running your code through a json lint tool to catch these sorts of issues.

Answer (score 0):

You've got curly quotes in there. Replace them with straight quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You have some sort of other quote character on this line (as well as some of your other lines):

`"default_popup": "popup.html”,`

as you can see, after popup.html you have a different style quotation mark (curly quote) - this will cause Chrome to believe it is a regular character, not a quote that ends a string value. I would replace it with a proper quote, and replace all of your curly quotes with this!